# Is there any limitation of what kind of Dictionary or Array I can store on UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have a `Dictionary` from Json that I want to store on `UserDefaults`, but I get error `Attempt to set a non-property-list object <object description here> as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key info`.

The thing is, my `Dictionary` is a multi level nested `Dictionary` which also has `Array` inside. But on the leaf nodes, all is just `String`. This is roughly the structure.

```
{
    data: {
        field1: "...",
        field2: "...",
        field3: [
            {
                info1: "...",
                info2: "...",
                info3: "..."
            },
            {
                info1: "...",
                info2: "...",
                info3: "..."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is this format cannot be stored into `UserDefaults`?

Thanks.

EDIT: as I narrowed down the problem, it seems that the problem is in the individual row of the `field3`. When I tried to save a dictionary of the individual row of the `field3` ex: `field3[0]`, it gave me the same error. But I have no problem if I save the entire json with the `field3` removed (set to nil).

Here is the actual content of one row of `field3`.

```
{
    "app_setting" = "app_setting_1";
    "created_at" = "2017-02-02 19:54:46";
    "feedback_name" = "No Toilet Paper";
    "feedback_option" = 1;
    id = "feedback_option_11";
    property = "property_1";
    sn = "<null>";
    "updated_at" = "2017-02-02 19:54:46";
    "url_image_option" = "https://example.com/assets/ios/option1.png";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set dictionaries, it doesn't matter what is there inside it like string, array.

**Objective C**

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[currentDefaults setObject:urDictionary forKey:@"yourKeyName"];

NSUserDefaults *retrieveDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *data1 = [retrieveDefaults objectForKey:@"yourKeyName"];
```

make sure that is a dictionary first

To convert an object to NSData

`NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:urObject];`

To retrieve an object

```
NSData *data1 = [retrieveDefaults objectForKey:@"yourKeyName"];
urObject *retrievedModel = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data1];
```

**Swift 3.0**

To convert a dictionary to data

```
let dataExample: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionaryExample)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dataExample, forKey:"yourKey")
```

To retrieve data:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourKey") as! NSDate
let dictionary: Dictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: dataExample) as! [String : Any]
```

Here is what apple says

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or for collections, a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

Comment: But according to article in here, you can save Dictionary and Array into UserDefaults. http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/ And what I'm going to save is Dictionary, which has Array inside it.

Comment: ok I got it, U r specifying a dictionary but field 3 has an array of dictionaries
 of kind `Any`

Comment: so u need to specify `let dict: [String:[[String:String]]]` or go with converting your dictionary to NSData

Comment: You can convert dictionary to NSData? Well that simplifies everything. Wait, let me tried it.

Comment: Alright, it works by converting to Data and back again. So this is all that I need. If it works, it works. No matter if it's a workaround lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using `Dictionary` or other supported data types listed in the [UserDefaults Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults), you should be fine. If that's the case and it still gives an error, you're building the dictionary incorrectly.

This solution works fine:

```
let dict: [String:Dictionary] = [
            "data": [
                "field1":["a","b","c"],
                "field2":["d","e","f"]
            ],
            "otherData": [
                "field1":["g","h","i"],
                "field2":["j","k","l"]
            ]
        ]

UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "dict")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: Is the code you posted exactly what you're trying to set as a dictionary? Note that `id`, `property` and `sn` are not strings and thus can't be dictionary keys.

Comment: that is the literal result of print to console of the object, which can produce object description like that because it is a dictionary.